# How can I resolve MAC knowing ipv6 addr w/o ip command?

Tags: ipv6

I installed OpenWrt on my router and I wanted to get MAC address of some machine connected to it. 
With ipv4 I would use `arp` command. But I want to resolve HW address knowing ipv6 addr. I have read that ipv6 has **ndp** protocol replacing **arp** and the command to lookup MAC table is `ip -6 neigh show`, but the problem is BusyBox in my OpenWrt does not have `ip` command and i am not sure if installing some package can bring it. So I wonder if there is any way to check MAC table for ipv6? Maybe I can just `cat` some file?

**Edit:** I installed **ip** package with `opkg` manager so now i can use `ip -6 neigh show`, but I'm still wondering if I can get the same info using `cat somefile`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use install ndpmon package:

```
apt-get install ndpmon


ndpmon - IPv6 Neighbor Discovery Protocol Monitor

root@lvm:/home/mohsen# dpkg -L ndpmon
/.
/etc
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/ndpmon
/etc/default
/etc/default/ndpmon
/etc/ndpmon
/etc/ndpmon/config_ndpmon.dtd
/etc/ndpmon/config_ndpmon.xml
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/ndpmon
/usr/lib/ndpmon/plugins
/usr/lib/ndpmon/plugins/mac_resolv
/usr/lib/ndpmon/plugins/mac_resolv/README
/usr/lib/ndpmon/plugins/mac_resolv/wka.tmpl
/usr/lib/ndpmon/plugins/mac_resolv/manuf.tmpl
/usr/lib/ndpmon/plugins/mac_resolv/manuf
/usr/lib/ndpmon/plugins/countermeasures
/usr/lib/ndpmon/plugins/countermeasures/icmp_lib.dox
/usr/lib/ndpmon/plugins/countermeasures/countermeasures.dox
/usr/lib/ndpmon/create_html_table.py
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man8
/usr/share/man/man8/config_ndpmon.xml.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/ndpmon.8.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/ndpmon
/usr/share/doc/ndpmon/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/ndpmon/copyright
/usr/share/doc/ndpmon/examples
/usr/share/doc/ndpmon/examples/demopipeprogram.pl.sample
/usr/share/doc/ndpmon/README
/usr/share/doc/ndpmon/changelog.gz
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/ndpmon
/usr/share/python-support
/usr/share/python-support/ndpmon.private
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/ndpmon
/var
/var/lib
/var/lib/ndpmon
/var/lib/ndpmon/neighbor_list.xml
/var/lib/ndpmon/neighbor_list.dtd
/var/lib/ndpmon/alerts.xml
root@lvm:/home/mohsen# man ndpmon
root@lvm:/home/mohsen# apt-cache search ndpmon
ndpmon - IPv6 Neighbor Discovery Protocol Monitor
```

Comment: `Unknown package 'ndpmon'.`
There is no `ndpmon` for OpenWrt :) But i installed `ip` with `opkg install ip` and now can apply `ip -6 neigh show`. Anyway im still wondering if i can `cat` some file to get same info.

Comment: http://ndpmon.sourceforge.net/